# Google App Engine dispatch.yaml Validation error PHP module

Tags: php, google-app-engine, redirect

I have the following error when I update dispatch.yaml.

> Error 400: --- begin server output ---
>   Validation error: Invalid dispatch configuration - module 'redirect' does not exist. Upload a version of this module and try again.
>   --- end server output ---

app.yaml

> application: test
>   module: default
>   version: 1-1
>   runtime: php55
>   api_version: 1
>   threadsafe: yes
>   handlers:
>   - url: /(.*)
>     static_files: index.html
>     upload: index.html

redirect.yaml

> application: test
>   module: redirect
>   version: 1-1
>   runtime: php55
>   api_version: 1
>   threadsafe: yes
>   handlers:
>   - url: /
>     script: routing.php

dispatch.yaml

> dispatch:
>   - url: "example.com/*"
>
>     module: redirect
>
>
>   - url: "*/*"
>     module: default

Could I fix it?

Comment: What command are you using to deploy?

Comment: @Chris I've tried to using appcfg.py -A test update /folder, and appcfg.py -A test update_dispatch /folder. Both are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `appcfg.py update` on a folder only the default module specified by `app.yaml` will be uploaded. You need to specify any additional modules you want to upload separately.